# I want to use SaveSetting command of VB6 with a ListView

Tags: vb6

My Code-

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim i
For i = 1 To GetSetting("Listview", "items", "c")
ListView1.ListItems.Add i, , GetSetting("Listview", "items", "li" & i)
Next i
MsgBox ListView1.ListItems.count
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
Dim i
Dim count
If ListView1.ListItems.count = 0 Then
count = 1
Else
count = ListView1.ListItems.count
End If
For i = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.count
SaveSetting "Listview", "items", "li" & i, ListView1.ListItems(i).Text
Next
SaveSetting "Listview", "items", "c", ListView1.ListItems.count
End Sub
```

I need to save the values of all rows in all cols. Please help.

Comment: And what is not working? MUST you do this saving to the registry? It is just plain text, you can use some file I/O instead.

Answer (score 0):

use vsflexgrid instead of listview
you can save flexgrid in a file & reload it again

just see the syntax

to save

```
VSFlexGrid1.SaveGrid “C:\test.doc”, flexFileAll
```

to Load

```
VSFlexGrid1.loadGrid “C:\test.doc”, flexFileAll
```

for more info please check

http://www.fredshack.com/docs/vsflex.html

or componentone's website